# printing two things upon a condition match in sml

Tags: sml

```
if (1=1)
then print "sdfsdfs" and print "sdfsdfsdfsdf"
else print "sdfsdf";
```

This gives an error. I want to do two things if the condition matches. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parenthesize the commands and separate them with a semicolon:

```
if 1=1
then (print "sdfsdfs"; print "sdfsdfsdfsdf")
else print "sdfsdf"
```